# Minecraft Crashes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I press play on my Minecraft launcher it starts to load, then goes back to the launcher.
This is what it tells me:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Everything's going to plan. No, really, that was supposed to happen.

Time: 4/30/17 8:47 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at azi.ad(SourceFile:325)
    at azi.f(SourceFile:688)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:152)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at azi.ad(SourceFile:325)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at azi.f(SourceFile:688)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:152)
```

Comment: pls help even when i latest version the too it shows this

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to reinstall the latest version of [Java](https://java.com/de/download/) and try again. Also update your graphics driver because openGL is mentioned in the error log you provided. This helps in many of this cases.